# mavericks always asks for password on boot

Tags: passwords, osx-mavericks

i have already gone through the login options in system preferences and my username is in the automatic login.

i recently upgraded to OSX 10.9 and have not been able to figure it out.

is it possible to have the laptop login automatically without requiring my password?

Answer (score 1):

IF it's not a special Mavericks issue (I'm avoiding it like the plague until I see a lot less traffic about "I upgraded and it broke...") Try disabling auto-login and then re-enabling it. Toss in a reboot or two to be thorough. Sometimes it gets out of whack - that usually cures it, IME.

Comment: And for good measure, through in the usual permission repair.